# How do I make items in a navigation wrap down to the next line when I change the viewport size?

Tags: list, navigation, word-wrap, items

How do you make the list items wrap down to the next line in a navigation like when you resize the page down from desktop size down to tablet sized viewport? I need my list items to go down to the next line as I change the screen size.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I tried to use this display inline block but I cant get them to wrap to the next line. I have four list items and I want them to wrap to the next line when I shrink the viewport. I have it set the viewport flexed and Im using justify content when the viewport is at desktop size.